# How to get second preceding sibling in XML in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, tags, lxml

I have an XML I want to iterate. I need to find the preceding node of a specific one (with tag "text" and attribute "bbox"). Problem is, I want to specify if the tag has no "bbox" attribute, to not care about it and get the element before. But I have no idea on how to do it. Here is the code:

```
 import lxml.etree as etree

from lxml.builder import E

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('fe3.xml', parser)
root = tree.getroot()

for x in tree.xpath('//text'):
        bb = x.attrib.get('bbox')
        if bb is not None:
            bb = bb.split(',')
        print('This: ', bb)
        xPrev = x.getprevious()
        bb = None
        if xPrev is not None:
            bb = xPrev.attrib.get('bbox')
            if bb is not None:
                bb = bb.split(',')
        if bb is not None:
            print('  Previous: ', bb)
        else:
            xx = bb.getprevious()
            print(xx, '  No previous bbox')
```

For clarity, my XML is structured like this (it is actually longer):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pages>
    <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
        <textbox id="0" bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
            <textline bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="192.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="193.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">P</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">T</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">L</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text></text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text></text>
            </textline>
        </textbox>
    </page>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me 100% what you're trying to achieve. That being said.

As you are looping through the bbox nodes you could simply add a variable and store the 'previous node' bbox inside.

**Here's the code I would use... if I am correct on what you want to achieve**

---

```py
x_prev = None
for x in tree.xpath('//text'):
        bb = x.attrib.get('bbox')
        if bb is not None:
            bb = bb.split(',')
        print('This: ', bb)

        if x_prev is not None:
            print('  Previous: ', x_prev)
        else:
            print('  No previous bbox')

        # Store this bounding box for the next loop (to be used as x_prev)
        x_prev = bb
```

---

*For clarity this code would replace your entire loop*

Comment: Thank you, but if I print bb[0] and x_prev[0] it's the same number...

Comment: In the code I provided you are sampling each node. You are printing out the current node and the previous node. If the current node and previous node have the same first term **`bb[0]`** than it will be the same number.

Can you run this code and share the output for a portion of your XML so I can gauge what might be happening?

Thanks!